# How to use both fabric.js and paper.js to make a drawing app?

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs, paperjs

I want to make a drawing app and I can't get the basic functionality to pan a layer nor to edit the `svgs` and scale, transform.

With `paper.js` the canvas can be easily resized and fit a div but I need the `fabric.js` to move and scale objects. Fabric does not resize or fit a `div`.

In html I  have this : `<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>`

and css :

```
#canvas {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

With this code I can resize the window and the canvas.

But when I use `fabric.js` it goes back to 300 x 150 and doesn't resize:

```
   var fabric = require('fabric').fabric;
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

    paper.install(window);
    window.onload = function() {
    // Setup directly from canvas id:
    paper.setup('canvas');
    var path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    var start = new Point(100, 100);
    path.moveTo(start);
    path.lineTo(start.add([ 200, -50 ]));
    view.draw();
   }
```

Comment: Add some part of the code here to be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that using `fabric.js` with `paper.js` is a good idea as they might have some conflicting points.
If what you lack from `fabric.js` is the ability to resize the canvas, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLqaf70s/) demonstrating how you can do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.1.0/fabric.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin : 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>

    // Init Fabric.js canvas
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

    // Draw rectangle
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
        left: 200,
        top: 200,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        fill: '#D81B60',
        hasControls: true
    }));

    // Bind and call resize callback
    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();

    // On resize...
    function resize() {
        // ...set canvas size to window size
        canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixes it but now paper does not work and i need it to edit the svg paths like in illustrator, or can that be done with fabric too?

Comment: I don't really know what you want to do but I don't think that either fabric or paper as a built-in way to edit a path like in illustrator. You will have to implement it yourself and I think that you can do it with both. The closest fabric example I can see is this: http://fabricjs.com/quadratic-curve